# Want to connect two independent BLE devices usig Flutter BLE libraries

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Current functionality of app is connect to a specific BLE device and fetch the device data in flutter App.

What I want to achieve is explained in below scenario:

We have
1 flutter app using the BLE libraries/plugins(which can connect to Device A and Device B).
2 BLE device A.
3 BLE device B.

Device A and Device B are Beacon esp32 devices

we want to establish a BLE connection between Device A and Device B through Flutter App.

Is is possible to implement above in Flutter using BLE plugins? Or do we have to come up with different solution.

Comment: What kind of devices are Device A and Device B? Smartphones running your app?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan these devices are not mobile phones, these are beacon esp32 devices which detects the temperature of surrounding.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `BLE connection between Device A and Device B through Flutter App`. Do you want to read from Device A and write the result to Device B?